# Setting the RadioButton "Selected" style in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I believe the `RadioButton` "selected" style is not getting set properly.

I am trying to style the radio button using the standard UIID `RadioButton` in the theme.

> I updated the unselected font style to black.
>
> I updated the selected and pressed font style to teal.

It looks like the pressed style works but the selected style does not work. Such that when the radio button is pressed, the font switches to teal but after it gets selected, the font reverts back to black.

Here is the code I used for testing.

```
Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
hi.addComponent(new RadioButton("Button 1"));
hi.addComponent(new RadioButton("Button 2"));
hi.addComponent(new RadioButton("Button 3"));
hi.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

First it seems you didn't add the radio buttons to a `ButtonGroup` which means the radio button won't be selected properly.

Notice the selected style applies to focus of the component and will only appear on touch. It isn't related to the `selected` state in the radio button which means checked (sorry about that confusing terminology).

I'm guessing you are trying to customize the check symbol which you can customize via [theme constants](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-theming.html).